# Is there any use in importing both ES6 and ES7 core-js polyfills?

Tags: javascript, polyfills

Is it useful or redundant to import the ES6 polyfill for `Object`

```
import 'core-js/es6/object';
```

and also the ES7 polyfill for `Object`?

```
import 'core-js/es7/object';
```

Does the ES7 polyfill cover all of the ES6 features and can I leave the ES6 polyfill out, or does the ES6 polyfill add features not present in the ES7 polyfill?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<sup>*This answer concerns `core-js@2`. Starting from `core-js@3`, there are no longer separate ES6 and ES7 prefixes. This is due to how ECMAScript developed. You can find more details in the [core-js@3, babel and a look into the future](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/docs/2019-03-19-core-js-3-babel-and-a-look-into-the-future.md#packages-entry-points-and-modules-names) post.*</sup>

Yes, there is a use. Simply compare [`core-js/es6/object.js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/v2/es6/object.js) to [`core-js/es7/object.js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/v2/es7/object.js).

The ES6 object polyfill provides:
•  [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)
•  [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
•  [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)
•  [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)
•  [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)
•  [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)
•  [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
•  [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)
•  [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)
•  [`Object.seal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)
•  [`Object.preventExtensions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions)
•  [`Object.isFrozen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isFrozen)
•  [`Object.isSealed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isSealed)
•  [`Object.isExtensible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isExtensible)
•  [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
•  [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is)
•  [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)
•  [`Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

On the other hand, the ES7 object polyfill provides:
•  [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors)
•  [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
•  [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
•  [`Object.prototype.__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__)
•  [`Object.prototype.__defineSetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineSetter__)
•  [`Object.prototype.__lookupGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__lookupGetter__)
•  [`Object.prototype.__lookupSetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__lookupSetter__)

Thus, the ES6 polyfill indeed adds *only* methods introduced in ES6 and this is *not* covered by the ES7 polyfill. That one *only* adds methods introduced in ES7.

core-js appears to be structured the same way for other classes.

Comment: We had to use es7 in addition to es6 for `new Map()` support which I believe comes with Object.entries.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Github links are broken. Looks like they may have recategorized.

Answer (score 3):

The polyfills from [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) for different ECMAScript versions are mostly distinct. For example take a look at the object polyfill for [ES6](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/es6/object.js) and [ES7](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/es7/object.js).

So you need to import both if you want to have the features from ES6 and ES7 polyfilled.